# Gigabyte 970A-UD3P - FX-8320E - Kingston Hyper X Beast 8 GB 1866 MHz - POSTing problems

Tags: motherboard, am3

I just bought this system, and all pieces are brand new.  I installed all the pieces together, but the motherboard won't [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test#Progress_and_error_reporting) at all.  The fans of the CPU and GPU are turning, but it will not POST and (I think this is important) the front panel becomes useless.

It will not shutdown or reset after started.  I can't boot with the backup BIOS as stated in some forums (press and hold power button, or press and hold power and reset button) because of this.  Is the motherboard dead on arrival?  Is there something else I could look at?

Here is a list of things I tried:

- Replaced the stock thermal paste with another one
- Removed everything from the case, cleaned them up (in case there was some dust could short)
- Tried to boot the pc without the case (I placed the motherboard on top of the plastic case that it came with, inserted PSU, CPU, and GPU) and tried to boot it, but nothing
- Reinserted everything to the case and tried again but nada (I did insert one RAM module at every slot of the motherboard).
- I cleared the BIOS more than once with no apparent result (removed the battery and power from the PSU, circuit the clear CMOS jumpers, but nothing happens).

This is the motherboard: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5194#ov

This is the list of supported CPUs: http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=5194

This is the RAM: http://www.hyperxgaming.com/us/memory/beast (8 GB 1866 MHz cl9)

I do not have a speaker for the motherboard, so I cannot hear anything.  What drives me crazy though is that I can't press shutdown or reset on the front panel, which makes me believe there is some problem with the motherboard.  Any guesses?

Comment: You need a speaker or an error LED code or something.  It could be bent pins on the CPU.  It could be anything at this point

Comment: I will fix a broken one I have that needs some soldering, I will try to see if the motherboard tries to speak to me and I will report back.

Comment: Ok, i installed the one i fixed with the soldering iron and it is either broken or really the mobo does not beep at all.  I searched in like 5 stores near me and couldn't find a mobo speaker for sale, not even online.  Anything i could try? Could i force the motherboard to load the backup bios in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is really weird... I got the fan off, did not move the CPU at all, did not replace thermal paste, got the fan on again exactly like the first time and ***it booted***...

It found a corruption in the BIOS which it restored and all is well again in the world...